# Unmatched '. chef while bootstrapping node

Tags: chef-infra

```
D:\Chef\chef-repo>knife bootstrap HOSTNAME -x user -P pwd -N NodeClient1
Creating new client for NodeClient1
Creating new node for NodeClient1
Connecting to HOSTNAME
HOSTNAME Unmatched '.
HOSTNAME TMPDIR: Undefined variable.
HOSTNAME tmp=/tmp: Command not found.
HOSTNAME else: endif not found.
```

I looked into some suggestion but didn't resolve this. What is the main cause of this.Basically I setup workstation in windows the node which I am bootstrapping to chef server is redhat. Is there something I am missing?

Below is the verbose output:

```
    DEBUG: Looking for bootstrap template in /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.41/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/templates
DEBUG: Found bootstrap template in /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.9.41/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap/templates
DEBUG: Adding NODE_HOSTNAME
DEBUG: establishing connection to NODE_HOSTNAME:22
DEBUG: connection established
INFO: negotiating protocol version
DEBUG: local is `SSH-2.0-Ruby/Net::SSH_3.1.1 x86_64-linux'
DEBUG: remote is `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3'
DEBUG: read 840 bytes
DEBUG: received packet nr 0 type 20 len 836
INFO: got KEXINIT from server
INFO: sending KEXINIT
DEBUG: queueing packet nr 0 type 20 len 1684
DEBUG: sent 1688 bytes
INFO: negotiating algorithms
DEBUG: negotiated:
* kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
* host_key: ssh-rsa
* encryption_server: aes128-cbc
* encryption_client: aes128-cbc
* hmac_client: hmac-sha1
* hmac_server: hmac-sha1
* compression_client: none
* compression_server: none
* language_client:
* language_server:
DEBUG: exchanging keys
DEBUG: queueing packet nr 1 type 34 len 20
DEBUG: sent 24 bytes
DEBUG: read 152 bytes
DEBUG: received packet nr 1 type 31 len 148
DEBUG: queueing packet nr 2 type 32 len 140
DEBUG: sent 144 bytes
DEBUG: read 720 bytes
DEBUG: received packet nr 2 type 33 len 700
DEBUG: queueing packet nr 3 type 21 len 20
DEBUG: sent 24 bytes
DEBUG: received packet nr 3 type 21 len 12
DEBUG: beginning authentication of `user'
DEBUG: queueing packet nr 4 type 5 len 28
DEBUG: sent 52 bytes
DEBUG: read 52 bytes
DEBUG: received packet nr 4 type 6 len 28
DEBUG: trying none
DEBUG: queueing packet nr 5 type 50 len 44
DEBUG: sent 68 bytes
DEBUG: read 68 bytes
DEBUG: received packet nr 5 type 51 len 44
DEBUG: allowed methods: publickey,password
DEBUG: none failed
DEBUG: trying publickey
DEBUG: connecting to ssh-agent
ERROR: could not connect to ssh-agent
DEBUG: trying publickey (0f:51:e1:1c:40:b2:34:4b:4c:78:89:58:9b:2d:60:fb)
DEBUG: queueing packet nr 6 type 50 len 348
DEBUG: sent 372 bytes
DEBUG: read 68 bytes
DEBUG: received packet nr 6 type 51 len 44
DEBUG: allowed methods: publickey,password
DEBUG: trying password
DEBUG: queueing packet nr 7 type 50 len 76
DEBUG: sent 100 bytes
DEBUG: read 68 bytes
DEBUG: received packet nr 7 type 51 len 44
DEBUG: allowed methods: publickey,password
DEBUG: password failed
user@NODE_HOSTNAME's password:
DEBUG: queueing packet nr 8 type 50 len 76
DEBUG: sent 100 bytes
DEBUG: read 36 bytes
DEBUG: received packet nr 8 type 52 len 12
DEBUG: password succeeded
DEBUG: queueing packet nr 9 type 90 len 44
DEBUG: sent 68 bytes
DEBUG: read 52 bytes
DEBUG: received packet nr 9 type 91 len 28
INFO: channel_open_confirmation: 0 0 0 32768
INFO: sending channel request "pty-req"
DEBUG: queueing packet nr 10 type 98 len 60
INFO: sending channel request "exec"
DEBUG: queueing packet nr 11 type 98 len 7420
DEBUG: sent 7528 bytes
DEBUG: read 88 bytes
DEBUG: received packet nr 10 type 93 len 28
INFO: channel_window_adjust: 0 +2097152
DEBUG: received packet nr 11 type 99 len 12
INFO: channel_success: 0
DEBUG: read 104 bytes
DEBUG: received packet nr 12 type 94 len 28
INFO: channel_data: 0 8b
DEBUG: received packet nr 13 type 94 len 28
INFO: channel_data: 0 10b
```

[image]

Comment: I would turn up the debugging, but it might be an issue with mismatched newlines on the installer script. Try adding `-VV` to enable debug logging.

Comment: For the future, you need to leave a comment when updating things, editing the question doesn't notify respondents.

Comment: I'm confused, you said your workstation was a Windows machine, but the paths in that log don't look like Windows paths.

Comment: +1 for 2nd comment. Sorry I tried in windows it didn't work same I tried in redhat box so it didn't fix.The paths you see from my redhat machine.I tried in redhat to get some relevant details in web if it fails.But however we can configure from any machine.

Comment: What version of knife are you using and is this a custom bootstrap template?

Comment: The version of knife is 12.9.41.I have not used any custom bootstrap template. I changed the csh to bash of the chef node the above error doesn't arise but it hangs at the end.I updated the latest verbose. is it expected?

Comment: `DEBUG: password failed` it is waiting for a password

Comment: Which pwd is it node ssh login? then it asked user@NODE_HOSTNAME's password: after I entered it logged in and proceed ..

Comment: Yes, the `-P` option is for setting the SSH password.

Answer (score 0):

Unmatched '. This issue caused due to csh when I changed to bash it worked and there was another issue with ssh-agent which need to start the ssh process in the node to overcome the issue.